# Linear regression in theano

Tags: python, theano

What is the significance of `T.mean` in [this example](https://github.com/Newmu/Theano-Tutorials/blob/master/1_linear_regression.py)? I think `T.mean` would have made sense if the implementation were vectorized. Here the inputs `x` and `y` to `train(x, y)` are scalars, and `cost` only finds squared error of a single input, and iterates over the data.

```
cost = T.mean(T.sqr(y - Y))
gradient = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=w)
updates = [[w, w - gradient * 0.01]]

train = theano.function(inputs=[X, Y], outputs=cost, updates=updates, allow_input_downcast=True)

for i in range(100):
    for x, y in zip(trX, trY):
        train(x, y)

print w.get_value()
```

Removing `T.mean` had no impact on the output pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `T.mean` has no significance here. The cost function operates on a single training sample at once, so the "mean squared error" is really just the squared error of the sample.

This example implements linear regression via [stochastic gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent), an algorithm for online optimization. SGD iterates over samples one-by-one, as is the case in this example. However, in more complex scenarios, the dataset is often [processed in mini-batches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent#Iterative_method), which gives better performance and convergence properties.

I think that `T.mean` was left in the example as an artifact of mini-batch gradient descent, or to make it more explicit that the cost function is MSE.